# Determining if a browser stops scrips on scrolling

Tags: javascript, mobile, touch

So, as we're all learning, when doing web development, you can't know if a device is a "touch" device or not. However, one issue I'm coming up against is page interaction that relates to scrolling (animation, etc).

The issue on iOS, for example, is that an iPhone will stop all scripts until scrolling is complete. That can interfere with certain interactions and animations.

Of course, I could just use iScroll, but that's not always appropriate. Sometimes I'd rather just disable those behaviours, and write some alternate code. So, is there anyway to determine if a browser halts scripts on scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

"So, as we're all learning, when doing web development, you can't know if a device is a 'touch' device or not."

FC: Yes, you can! Quite recently, a new script has been written by the makers of Modernizr. From which I distilled an ultrashort and simple native JS, that eliminates the need to include Modernizr itself. See [**this SO thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24639330/touchscreen-detection-script-revised-community-testing-wanted). And so far, I have not read a single report of it not functioning.